# Equivalent of ASP.NET HttpModules in PHP

Tags: php, asp.net

what is the equivalent of ASP.NET HttpModules in PHP?

If there are any how can I include them for that specific application (not globally) in other words what is the equivalent of web.config

Example : I need to log the request and the headers, if the server is returning a HTTP 500 error irrespective of the code which is run.

In ASP.NET, I would have a HTTP Module in which I can grab the response code and other details, before sending to the client. I can also handle Begin Request.

I need something similar in PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately PHP is more like ASP in the sense that the "application" is a loose concept, the files are not tightly related, so anything you do would likely have to be at the web server level

Assuming you are on a linux/apache server.  One approach would be to use .htaccess, these can be modified at the directory (ie application level) and have sever powerful features.

One example is for url re-writing:

http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/02/hide-php-url-rewriting-htaccess.html

Official Apache Docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: @brendan - If I understand URL Re Writing is similar to Routing. What I am looking for is a way to get my code executed before the processing goes to the PHP page present in the Directory.

Comment: gotcha - I assumed you were using the HTTP Module for re-writing urls (one common task) you can used the .htaccess file modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can look the ModSecurity for Apache: http://www.modsecurity.org/

It will allow you to log full POST and headers data depending on rules you define.
ModSecurity configuration is very powerful but very complex too.

> HTTP Traffic Logging
>
> Web servers are typically
>   well-equipped to log traffic in a form
>   useful for marketing analyses, but
>   fall short logging traffic to web
>   applications. In particular, most are
>   not capable of logging the request
>   bodies. Your adversaries know this,
>   and that is why most attacks are now
>   carried out via POST requests,
>   rendering your systems blind.
>   ModSecurity makes full HTTP
>   transaction logging possible, allowing
>   complete requests and responses to be
>   logged. Its logging facilities also
>   allow fine-grained decisions to be
>   made about exactly what is logged and
>   when, ensuring only the relevant data
>   is recorded. As some of the request
>   and/or response may contain sensitive
>   data in certain fields, ModSecurity
>   can be configured to mask these fields
>   before they are written to the audit
>   log.

Comment: @Julien - Thanks for the link. But that was an example. All I want is a way to handle BeginRequest and EndRequest for all requests coming into the directory.